# Right click menu css

Tags: css, right-click

Basically I just wanted to know how to change the looks of the right click menu using css. I haven't tried anything because I have no clue were to start.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to make at least _some_ attempt to solve this yourself. General questions about where to start or how to do research are considered off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately, you can't change the right click menu style using CSS, but you can disable it and create one from scratch using HTML, CSS and Javascript

you can handle the right click event (context menu event) by adding this code:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

This part `e.preventDefault();` will disable the default behavior of the right click and the context menu will no longer appear, now you need to add a function and new style for your styled context menu

If you are still not sure how to make this here's a tutorial for the complete thing you want to achieve https://www.sitepoint.com/building-custom-right-click-context-menu-javascript/

Comment: Thank you this really helps me <3